# What coding projects are used to create art and beauty?

Tags: matrix

Today the blinkenlights [stereoscope](http://blinkenlights.net/stereoscope) project starts as part of the [nuit blanche](http://www.scotiabanknuitblanche.ca/) art event in Toronto. The Toronto city hall is transferred into a giant matrix display. There are [tools](http://blinkenlights.net/stereoscope/create) to create custom animations and an [iphone application](http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=291807780&mt=8) to view the live stream.

[image: blinkenlights]

I think this is a great example of using technology for art and beauty. What other coding/programming projects are out there for the sake of art and beauty?

Update:
Youtube Video of blinkenlights in action: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jTZosieGhIQ

Answer (score 4):

There's a ton of art projects involving technology / code over at [processing.org](http://processing.org/exhibition/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

I've tinkered with http://processing.org here and there over the last few years. Along similar lines, there's the Context Free project, at http://www.contextfreeart.org

The idea behind Context Free is very cool. Rather than directly placing graphic elements, using imperative semantics, you define a grammar that declaratively defines the relationship of graphic elements. The runtime system generates an image by walking the grammar and instantiating elements that conform with its rules.

Fun stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I find [code_swarm](http://web.archive.org/web/20180610233621/http://vis.cs.ucdavis.edu:80/~ogawa/codeswarm/) totally beautiful, awe inspiring and hypnotic, does that count?

[image]
<sub>(source: [ucdavis.edu](http://web.archive.org/web/20180610233621/http://vis.cs.ucdavis.edu:80/~ogawa/codeswarm/eclipse-640px.png))</sub>

Comment: Of course this counts! I found it very impressing to see python evolve over the time and to see how long some known contributors have been onboard.

Comment: code_swarm is incredibly beautiful. If I am not mistaken, it was implemented using processing.org.

Answer (score 2):

Personaly I think this is a great example of using code to produce art and not only that but the art expresses something all geek types can understand and respect http://www.opte.org/maps/
[image]
<sub>(source: [bitgravity.com](http://bitcast-a.v1.sjc1.bitgravity.com/blyon/opte/maps/static/1105841711.LGL.2D.400x400.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Any place where you will find contemporary art, so museums and art festivals.  Interactive installations often use a dataflow programming language such as max/msp or puredata to process input and do something interesting with it.

There are also festivals which focus more on how code can be used to create art.  An example is http://piksel.no in Bergen, Norway.  Piksel.no has seminars and workshops, live events, etc..  There are similar festivals in other countries.

And you could stretch the definition of art a bit and include the demoscene.  I do consider some demoscene productions to be art, but they are rare gems among the drudge.  Still, have a look at http://scene.org/awards.php to get some idea of what kind of stuff that community comes up with.

Comment: I think you don't have to strech the definition to call the demo scene art. But the difference is imho that it seldom does the step to broad audience like the blinkenlights project.

Answer (score 1):

Every code project you work on should be a form of art, and wonderful to behold.

I am only being partly facetious here.  Part of why people enjoy computer programming is the  sculptural/artistic nature of the whole thing.  Code for beauty of structure and appearance, and you often also have better code...

Answer (score 1):

The computer program [AARON](http://www.kurzweilcyberart.com/) by Harold Cohen has been painting artwork for over 30 years.

[image]
<sub>(source: [ucsd.edu](http://web.archive.org/web/20130704144023/http://crca.ucsd.edu/~hcohen/images/hc.gif))</sub>

Comment: Bummer. It looks like the AARON software is no longer available for download.